# Property 'checkPassword' does not exist on type 'User'

Tags: nestjs, jwt

My **authservice.ts** file as below:

```
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from '../users/users.service';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { LoginUserDto } from 'src/users/dto/loginUser.dto';
import { JwtPayload } from './interfaces/jwt-payload.interface';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private usersService: UsersService,
    private jwtService: JwtService,
 ) {}

  async validateUserByPassword(loginAttempt: LoginUserDto) {

  // This will be need used for the initial login
  let userToAttempt = await this.usersService.findOneByEmail(loginAttempt.email);

  return new Promise((resolve) => {

    // Check the supplied password against the hash stored for this email address
    userToAttempt.checkPassword(loginAttempt.password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) throw new UnauthorizedException();
      if (isMatch) {
        // If there is a successful match, generate a JWT for the user
        resolve(this.createJwtPayload(userToAttempt));

      } else {
          throw new UnauthorizedException();
      }
    });
 });
}

  async validateUserbyJwt(payload: JwtPayload) {

 //This will be used when the user has already logged in and has a JWT
 let user = await this.usersService.findOneByEmail(payload.email);

  if (user) {
   return this.createJwtPayload(user);
  } else {
   throw new UnauthorizedException();
  }
}

 createJwtload(user) {
  let data: JwtPayload = {
   email: user.mail
};

  let jwt = this.jwtService.sign(data);

  return {
    expiresIn: 3600,
    token: jwt
   }
 }
}
```

The validateUserByPassword method is used when the user is initially logging in with email and password. This method finds the user in the MongoDB that matches the supplied email and then it will invoke the custom checkPassword method added to the User schema.

**schemas.users.ts**

```
 import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
 import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

 export interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
    username: string,
    password:string
 }

 export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {
       type: String,
       required: [true, 'Please, Enter your Name'],
 },
    lastname: {
       type: String,
       required: [true, 'Please, Enter your Lastname'], 
 },
    password: {
       type: String,
       required: [true, 'Please Enter your Password'],
 },
    email: {
       type: String,
       unique:true,
       required: [true, 'Please Enter your Email'],
 },
    phone: {
       type: String,
       optional: true
 },
    address: {
       type: String,
       optional: true,
 },
    datecreated: { 
       type: Date, 
       default: Date.now }
});

UserSchema.pre<IUser>('save', function(next) {
 const user = this;

   //Make sure not to rehash the password if it is already rehashed
   if(!user.isModified('password')) {
    return next();
}
   //Generate a salt and use it to hash the user's password
   bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
   if (err) {
    return next(err);
   }
   bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err: mongoose.Error, hash) => {
   if (err) {
    return next(err);
   }
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});

UserSchema.methods.checkpassword = function(attempt, callback){

 const user = this;

bcrypt.compare(attempt, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
    if(err) return callback(err);
    callback(null, isMatch);
 });
};
```

If the hash of the supplied password matches the hash stored in the database for that user, the authentication will succeed. In that case, the method will return a JWT by calling the createJwtPayload method. The createJwtPayload method will add the user’s email address to the payload, and then it will sign the JWT using the sign method of the JwtService that was injected into the constructor.

However, i got an error:

```
src/auth/auth.service.ts:23:23 - error TS2339: Property 'checkPassword' does not exist on type'User'.
     23  userToAttempt.checkPassword(loginAttempt.password, (err, isMatch) => {
```

Could you please identify where is the problem?

Comment: You have typo: UserSchema.methods.checkpassword should be UserSchema.methods.checkPassword

Comment: Thank you. But same error occurred.

Comment: Where do you define the type `User`?